# Android blocking intent

Tags: android, android-intent, ipc, android-binder

Can my application block intents from other applications ?
I would like to block requests from specific applications,

How can it be done ?
I have access to the AOSP so I would like to understand where in the code I can add the blocking mechanism?

For example I would like to refuse to share something which arrives from the browser (for example a copy of the URL) with a specified application.

I see that intents goes to the activity manager, and the activity manager deliver it to the relevant application,
How can I know in the lower layer what is the origin of the request ?

For example:
am start -a android.intent.action.SEND -d "some message" -t text/plain
I see in the shell:
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND dat=some message typ=text/plain }
I/ActivityManager(  309): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.SEND dat=some message typ=text/plain flg=0x10000000 cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity} from pid 1149

How can I know in the lower layers that the origin process is 1149? I see in the binder that the request comes from 309 which is the activity manager, I would like to block process 1149
I can change the AOSP but I don't know where I can do it.

Comment: How about [intent service](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/app/IntentService.java)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using permissions. See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#perms) and [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#declaring).